# Automate Version Name in Install4j

Tags: maven, pom.xml, install4j

In install4j installer how can i automate version under General Setting-> ApplicationInfo->Version. So that version should always remain latest for my product installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line compiler has an option  `--release=VERSION` that allows you to set the project version externally. ant, gradle and maven integrations have corresponding parameters.

Comment: Is there any way to read version of a product defined in pom.xml and set it to General Setting-> ApplicationInfo->Version of product installer ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418215/automate-version-in-install4j-file-based-on-pom-version