# Automate version in .install4j file based on POM version

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, install4j

I am using Maven to automate build process of Install4j.

For every release product, POM version is updated. I want when pom version is updated Install4j version should be updated (under General Setting-> ApplicationInfo->Version).

How can i automate version in install4j file. So that version should always remain latest for my product installer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the release parameter for the install4j compile target to set the version from the maven plugin. See

http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html

for more information.